# CoreData Generated Accessors definition

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to move a method using these accessors in super class:

```
@interface CBComic (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCharactersObject:(CBCharacter *)value;
- (void)removeCharactersObject:(CBCharacter *)value;
- (void)addCharacters:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeCharacters:(NSSet *)value;
```

I've copied pasted the method declarations to my superclass but I get a warning that definition is not provided in the superclass.

The implementation is provided by Core Data, so how should I solve it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface YourSuperClass : NSManagedObject

...

@end

@interface YourSuperClass (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCharactersObject:(CBCharacter *)value;
- (void)removeCharactersObject:(CBCharacter *)value;
- (void)addCharacters:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeCharacters:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

Comment: But, then I have to refer to the SuperClass from the core data model ? I mean, should I change the class associated with the instance in the core data model from the current class to the superclass ?

Comment: I thought you were trying to suppress a compiler warning. Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.